# XAML Node Stream: Missing CurrentObject before EndObject

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, workflow

I'm getting below error in Workflow service. I've searched on google but does not find any helpful information. I found this link but unable to understand it.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba29b516-7ff4-4fea-b0a5-5ebda5283664/xaml-node-stream-missing-currentobject-before-endobject?forum=wfprerelease

The issue occurred randomly and Inner Exception is

`at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.InitializeComponentFromXamlResource(Type componentType, String resource, Object componentInstance, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext)
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.ActivityXamlServices.InitializeComponent(Type componentType, Object componentInstance)`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody needs an answer:
Remove references for System.Activities.Presentation, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase modules from the project.

Also check GC mode, in runtime it should reap benefits of running on multiple cores. To enable Server mode:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Please refer gcServer documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element